# Copying executable file in c

Tags: c, file-io, io

I am trying to copy an executable file in my c program. Please see code below:

```
int dumpDaExecutable(char *progpath){

char *base, *basec;

basec = strdup(progpath);

base = basename(basec);

printf("%s\n", base);

//rename(progpath, base);

FILE *ptr_of, *ptr_nf;

int x;

ptr_of = fopen(basec, "rb");
ptr_nf = fopen(base, "wb");

if(ptr_of == NULL){
    printf("Old file is NULL\n");
    return 1;
}

if(ptr_nf == NULL){
    printf("New file is NULL\n");
    fclose(ptr_of);
    return 1;
}

unsigned char c[4096];

while(1){

    //printf("in the while!\n");

    x = fread(c, 1, 4096, ptr_of);

    if(x < 1){
        if(x == 0)
            printf("success");
        break;
    }
    if(fwrite(c, x, 1, ptr_nf) != 1){
        break;
    }

}

fclose(ptr_nf);
fclose(ptr_of);
//free(base);
//free(basec);
return 0;

}
```

The progpath I am passing is */program - where * are the parent folders, and program is the actual executable. After my program has run, the new file that is created is empty. I am confused why this is happening. Is there something different you need to do when copying executable files?

The permissions on the program file are set to 777.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: the posted code, for safety, should be checking that the new file and the old file are not the same file.

Comment: the posted code should be checking for the success/failure of the calls to `fopen()` immediately after the calls, not some instructions later, and when `fopen()` fails, call `perror()` as that would also output the reason the OS thinks the call to `fopen()` failed.

Comment: please post a complete, minimal, verifiable code AND the actual command line you are using.

Comment: the posted code called `strdup()` but failed to pass the resulting pointer to `free(), so there is a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
if(fwrite(c, 1, x, ptr_nf) != x){
    // display error
    break;
}
```

To copy a file, you can do:

```
while fread(..)
    fwrite(..);
```

It is also a good habit to `#define` your buffer size:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 4096

// or use const int buffSize = 4096;

unsigned char c[BUFF_SIZE];

x = fread(c, 1, BUFF_SIZE, ptr_of);
```

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested and am still getting a blank file.

Comment: unsigned char c[BUFF_SIZE];

    while((x = fread(c, 1, BUFF_SIZE, ptr_of) != 0)){
        if(fwrite(c, 1, x, ptr_nf) != x){
            break;
        }

    }

Comment: Could you successfully open both files? Did you get any other errors? (maybe try to print the value of x inside your while loop or use the debugger)

Comment: Yes, I was able to successfully open both files without errors. If I use fread, and put a print statement in the while-loop, nothing is printed out. It doesn't even pass the condition making it into the while-loop. However, if I do        read = fgetc(ptr_of);   while(ptr_of != EOF){
     printf("%c", read);
   read = fgetc(ptr_of);
    } the loop never ends, and it just prints out unicode.

Comment: You'll have to check `ferror()` then - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: So, I did an lseek of the file after opening and it is giving a -1. If I am in the child directory of where the executable exists while the programming is running, would this cause any problems?

Comment: You will have to step tough this with a debugger. Also check the full filepaths + check errno after opening each file. Probably access rights or something. Are you sure the file isn't opened by another process?

Comment: this expression: `while(ptr_of != EOF)` will NEVER cause the loop to exit, as the `ptr_of` never changes.  However, the 'read' variable does change and that is what the code should be checking.  I.E.  `int myByte; while( (myByte = fgetc(ptr_of) != EOF) { printf("%c", myByte); }`.  BTW: `read` is a well known system function name and it is poor programming practice to use function names as variable names.